# Is it possible to implement a Widening Operator for SqlParameter?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Take the following class:

```
Public Class DocumentNumber
    Private m_DOC_NUMBER As Integer = 0

    Public Sub New(ByVal DOC_NUMBER As Integer)
        m_DOC_NUMBER = DOC_NUMBER
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal DEPOT_CODE As String)
        Dim ParseInput As Integer = 0
        If Integer.TryParse(DEPOT_CODE, ParseInput) = False Then
            m_DOC_NUMBER = 0
        Else
            m_DOC_NUMBER = ParseInput
        End If
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns the DOC_NUMBER as a zero-padded number, eg: 0000028374
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Right("0000000000" & m_DOC_NUMBER.ToString(), 10)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns the DOC_NUMBER as an integer, use .ToString() zero-padded version.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Function ToInteger() As Integer
        Return m_DOC_NUMBER
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Ensure that the DOC_NUMBER object has an implicit convert if assigned to an integer / string
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal d As DocumentNumber) As Integer
        Return d.ToInteger()
    End Operator

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal d As DocumentNumber) As String
        Return d.ToString()
    End Operator

End Class
```

This class allows me to declare a DocID from either a string or an integer:

```
Dim DocumentID As New DOC_NUMBER("00123")
Dim DocumentID As New DOC_NUMBER(123)
```

And these can be retreived in either format by calling `ToInteger()` & `ToString()`:

```
Dim NewDocumentID as Integer = DocumentID.ToInteger()
Dim NewDocumentID as String = DocumentID.ToString()
```

Note the two `Widening Operator`'s - these also allow implicit conversion meaning `.ToInteger()` and `.ToString()` can be omitted when assigning an instance of this class to an integer or string, for example:

```
Dim NewDocumentID as Integer = DocumentID
Dim NewDocumentID as String = DocumentID
```

So far; this all works great, my next challenge is adding an implicit conversion when assigned to a `SqlParameter()` object.

As you know, if you assign an object to a new `SqlParameter()`, the data type can be omitted and the `SqlParameter()` object will figure this out automatically - however, if I try this with my object it obviously fails:

```
m_db_QueryParams.Add(New SqlParameter("@DOC_NUMBER", OrderNumber))
```

**This gives the following error (And understandably so!):**

*No mapping exists from object type DocumentNumber to a known managed provider native type.*

My Question: Is it possible to add a `Widening Operator` to my class that will Return it's `.ToString()` method when being assigned to a `SqlParameter()` with no data type supplied (like this):

```
m_db_QueryParams.Add(New SqlParameter("@DOC_NUMBER", OrderNumber)) 'Convert as a string for the SqlParameter
```

I've tagged this question as both VB & c# as a solution in either language would be suitable.

Comment: How about a function `ToSqlParameter(parameterName as string) as SqlParameter` where you create and return a new SqlParameter and excplicitly state the SqlDataType and then call it like `m_db_QueryParams.Add(OrderNumber.ToSqlParameter("@DOC_NUMBER"))`?

Comment: Might as well just call the `.ToString()` method if that's the case :) The whole point of this is to take the onus off the developer to pick the correct `.ToX()` method (The SQL `@DOC_NUMEBER` param will always require a string) don't want the developer having to type `.ToString()` every time they use it in SQL when I should be able to implicitly perform this conversion automatically - hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `SqlParameter` constructor take a parameter of the type `Object`.

Since all classes inherit from `Object` your widening operator will not be called when you add  your value.

This is because your value with type `DocumentNumber` is already of the type `Object` an no conversion to `String` is needed.

I think you best bet will be to create some code pattern. You could create an extension method on SqlParameterCollection like:

```
Module SqlParameterExtensions

  <Extension()>
  Public Sub MyAddWithValue(coll As SqlParameterCollection, paramName As String, paramValue As Object)
    If (TypeOf paramValue Is DocumentNumber) Then
        coll.AddWithValue(paramName, paramValue.ToString())
    Else
        coll.AddWithValue(paramName, paramValue)
    End If
  End Sub
End Module
```

And call it like

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim com As New SqlCommand
        Dim docNo As New DocumentNumber
        com.Parameters.MyAddWithValue("@DOC_NO", docNo)
    End Sub

End Module
```

or you could crate a "factory" method for SqlParameters;

```
Public Shared Function CreateParameter(name As String, value As Object) As SqlParameter
    If (TypeOf value Is DocumentNumber) Then
        value = value.ToString()
    End If

    Return New SqlParameter(name, value)
End Function
```

Comment: Hmm, until educated otherwise I’m going to have to agree; I think what I want isn’t possible for the reasons you state, I’ll go ahead and accept this as the answer & will just have to accept that I’ll need to call .ToString() on my object whenever I pass it to a SqlParameter. Thanks again for your input.